# Lagrange multiplier understanding problem

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I do have a problem with the lagrange mutiplier method.
I understand how it works for something like:
maximize $f(x,y)$ subject to $g(x,y)=c$.

But how do I handle something like:
Maximize f(x,y) subject to $g(x,y)=||(x,y)||^2 \leq 1$.
What I did (and it worked for this particular exercise) is that i just set $g(x,y)=||(x,y)||-c$ for a $ c \in [0,1]$ and then it happened to be sufficient for just one c.

Does this always work? I saw a solution which first checked all points where the gradient of g(x,y) and f(x,y) is 0 and then conluded that the those are the only possible solutions on the inner points of the set which fullfils $||x|| \leq 1$

Can someone explain me how this is all related?

Thanks!

Comment: The Lagrange multiplier method also works for inequality constraints.  See the Kuhn-Tucker conditions here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions

Comment: Intuitively for just 1 constraint:  If there is a solution where the constraint is slack (or "inactive"), it will also be a local min for the unconstrained problem of maximizing $f(x,y)$.  If not, then optimality for the constrained problem always occurs when the constraint is met with equality, in which cas the inequality constraint can be equivalently replaced by an equality constraint anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a two-dimensional analogue of something you are probably familiar with: Suppose a differentiable function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is restricted to an interval $[a,b]$ and you want to find the extrema there. Then, the procedure you follow is:

1. Find the local extrema in $(a,b)$ by checking the values of $x$ in $(a,b)$for which  $f'(x)=0$ or $f'(x)$ is undefined.
2. Evaluating $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.
3. Selecting the largest and smallest value(s) from 1. and 2.

The procedure works because $f$ is differentiable, hence continuous on the compact set $[a,b]$.

Now, in your case, you have a (presumably differentiable) $f:\mathbb R^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb R$, restricted to the set of points $(x,y)$ for which $||(x,y)||^2 \leq 1$.

This set is just the unit disk and its interior, which is compact and so we may use the corresponding result for such functions on $\mathbb R^{2}$:

1. Find the local extrema in the interior of the region by locating the points $(x,y)$ for which $\nabla f(x,y)=0$ or $\nabla f(x,y)$ is undefined.
2. Evaluating the values of $f$ on the disk i.e. on the set of points $(x,y)$ for which $||(x,y)||^2 = 1$.
3. Selecting the largest and smallest value(s) from 1. and 2.

Part 2. can be tricky, but in this special case, it might be easier to consider $f(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ and the values of $\theta $ that make $f$ maximum/minimum.

Comment: Thanks! I somehow didn't realize that for a min/max $(a,b)$ in the interior $\nabla f(a,b)=0$.

Comment: @user254331: if the gradient vanishes, then the tangent plane is horizontal  and so just like in the one-dimensional case, you have several possibilities, which you check by using the [second derivative test for multivariable functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test).

Answer (score 0):

The theory for inequality constraints, that is $g(x,y) \le 1$, is much more complicated than for equations like $g(x,y) = 1$. As start you could consult the Wikipedia on [Karush–Kuhn–Tucker conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions).

However, in your simple case $f,g:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$, it boils down to following: 
You can first try to find a maximizer in the interior, that is, $\nabla f(x,y)$ needs to be zero. If such interior optimizer does not exist, you can try to find one on the boundary. That is, the gradient of Lagrangian to the constraint $g(x,y)=1$ needs to be zero.

As for sufficient condition for a maximizer at the boundary: 
Let $(x^*,y^*)\in\mathbb R^2$ and $\lambda^* \ge 0$ such that 
$$ \nabla f(x^*, y^*) + \lambda^* \nabla g(x^*, y^*) = 0 $$
and
$$ g(x^*,y^*)=1.$$
If the Hessian of the Lagrangian 
$$ \nabla^2 f(x^*, y^*) + \lambda^* \nabla^2 g(x^*, y^*) $$
is negativ definit.
Then, $(x^*,y^*)$ is a maximizer.